# How to find word index or position in a given string using r programming

Tags: r

How to find index or position of a word in a given string, below code says the starting position of word and length. After finding the position of the word, I want to extract preceding and succeeding words in my project.

```
library(stringr)
Output_text <- c("applicable to any future potential contract termination disputes as the tepco dispute was somewhat unique")

word_pos <- regexpr('termination', Output_text)


Output:

[1] 45
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 11
attr(,"index.type")
[1] "chars"
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

45 - It is counting each and every character and displaying starting position of "termination"

11- is length

Here, "termination", is at 7th position, how to find it using r programming

Appreciate your help.

Comment: `grepl` plus `strsplit` or `which` or `str_detect` might help.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
library(stringr)

Output_text <- c("applicable to any future potential contract termination disputes as the tepco dispute was somewhat unique")

words <- unlist(str_split(Output_text, " "))

which(words == "termination")
[1] 7
```

Edit:

For multiple occurrences of the word in text and generating next and previous keywords:

```
# Adding a few random "termination" words to the string:

Output_text <- c("applicable to any future potential contract termination disputes as the tepco dispute was termination somewhat unique termination")

words <- unlist(str_split(Output_text, " "))

t1 <- which(words == "termination")
next_keyword <- words[t1+1]
previous_keywords <- words[t1-1]

> next_keyword
[1] "disputes" "somewhat" NA        
> previous_keywords
[1] "contract" "was"      "unique"
```

Comment: Basically, you need to use `str_split` from `stringr` package to split the character string into elements at each space, creating a new character vector `words`. Then search it for matching word with `which ( ) `

Comment: Thank you @denisafonin for very quick reply. Now how do I extract next word, below code is not helping me                                                                             t1 <- which(words == "termination")
next_keyword = substr(words,t1,t1+1)

Comment: `next_keyword <- words[t1+1]`

Comment: Fantastic, this helps to proceed further. Thank you @denisafonin

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy great! Please, consider marking the answer as correct if it helps you

Comment: Sure, will do that. Got one more issue here, this text file is bigger and termination word is appearing more than once, now I want to extract all the instances and validate them by looking at previous and next keyword. How to extract all the instances?

Comment: This code will work equally fine for multiple occurrences. I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without worrying about character indices using regular expressions without any external package.

```
# replace whole string by the words preceding and following 'termination'
(words <- sub("[\\S\\s]+ (\\S+) termination (\\S+) [\\S\\s]+", "\\1 \\2", Output_text, perl = T))
# [1] "contract disputes"

# Split the resulting string into two individual strings
(words <- unlist(strsplit(words, " ")))
# [1] "contract" "disputes"
```

Comment: how it works when it appears more than once?
Output_text <- c("applicable to any future potential contract termination disputes as the tepco dispute was termination somewhat unique,test1 termination test2")

Comment: I tried it, but it returns only first instance.
Output_text <- c("applicable to any future potential contract termination disputes as the tepco dispute was termination somewhat unique,test1 termination test2")

(words <- sub("[\\S\\s]+ (\\S+) termination (\\S+) [\\S\\s]+", "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", Output_text, perl = T))
(words <- unlist(strsplit(words, " ")))
output:
[1] "contract" "disputes" ""

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just the match `termination` and the surrounding words in `str_extract` and then `str_remove` `termination`.

```
str_remove(str_extract(Output_text,"\\w+ termination \\w+"),"termination ")
[1] "contract disputes"
```

Comment: Thank you James, this also works. What if the keyword is present more than once, how to handle that? How to display all the instances?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Use `str_extract_all`

Comment: it doesn't work above code
    Output_text <- c("applicable to any future potential contract termination disputes as the tepco dispute was somewhat unique, test1 termination test2")
    str_remove(str_extract_all(Output_text,"\\w+ sector perform \\w+"),"sector perform ")

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Where does sector perform come from?

Comment: ohh… that is other code. str_remove(str_extract_all(Output_text,"\\w+ termination \\w+"),"termination")