# Finding adjacent values in a list

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to the one below consisting of Unit and List columns. The goal is to find the matching value in [List] from [Unit], as well as the adjacent values -1 and +1 index of it. The desired output is shown in [Adjacent]. Eg in row 1, find 1 from list (1 2 3) and return (1 2).

| Unit | List | Adjacent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 2 3 | 1 2 |
| 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 20 | 10 20 30 | 10 20 30 |
| 2 | 1 2 | 1 2 |
| 3 | 1 2 3 4 | 2 3 4 |
| 4A | 2A 3A 4A 5A | 3A 4A 5A |

I tried to replicate the line of thinking proposed in similar questions (below) to no avail. Unfortunately, I'm still quite new to r and has yet been able to think of a solution to this.

Would appreciate some suggestions to this problem. Thanks!

Similar questions

[How to find word index or position in a given string using r programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090663/how-to-find-word-index-or-position-in-a-given-string-using-r-programming)

[Apply function on each cell in a column and add the result to a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354524/apply-function-on-each-cell-in-a-column-and-add-the-result-to-a-new-column)

Comment: Is `List` a list column or a character column? Can you provide data in a reproducible format using `dput` ? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option using `strsplit` + `mapply` (borrow `df` from [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68691639/12158757))

```
transform(
  df,
  Adjacent = mapply(
    function(x, k) paste0(x[abs(seq_along(x) - which(x == k)) <= 1], collapse = " "),
    strsplit(List, "\\s+"),
    Unit
  )
)
```

gives

```
  Unit        List Adjacent
1    1       1 2 3      1 2
2   10          10       10
3   20    10 20 30 10 20 30
4    2         1 2      1 2
5    3     1 2 3 4    2 3 4
6   4A 2A 3A 4A 5A 3A 4A 5A
```

Comment: nice answer.  I think I can apply my regex approach in baseR too

Comment: Thank you for this easy to understand solution! Works correctly!

Answer (score 3):

One more option using `regex` (borrowing example df by Ronak).

**baseR approach**

```
transform(df, 
          Adjacent = mapply(function(.x, .y) regmatches(.y, 
                                                        regexpr(paste0('[^ ]* *' , .x, ' *[^ ]*'), .y)), 
                            Unit, 
                            List))

   Unit        List Adjacent
1     1       1 2 3      1 2
10   10          10       10
20   20    10 20 30 10 20 30
2     2         1 2      1 2
3     3     1 2 3 4    2 3 4
4A   4A 2A 3A 4A 5A 3A 4A 5A
```

---

**Tidyverse approach**

```r
df <- structure(list(Unit = c("1", "10", "20", "2", "3", "4A"), 
                     List = c("1 2 3", "10", "10 20 30", "1 2", "1 2 3 4", "2A 3A 4A 5A")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Adjacent = map2(Unit, List, ~regmatches(.y, regexpr(paste0('[^ ]* *' , .x, ' *[^ ]*'), .y))))
#>   Unit        List Adjacent
#> 1    1       1 2 3      1 2
#> 2   10          10       10
#> 3   20    10 20 30 10 20 30
#> 4    2         1 2      1 2
#> 5    3     1 2 3 4    2 3 4
#> 6   4A 2A 3A 4A 5A 3A 4A 5A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the data on whitespace to create list column use `match` to get index of `Unit` and return values at +1 and -1 position.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  #you don't need strsplit if data is already a list
  mutate(List = strsplit(List, '\\s+'),       
         Adjacent = map2(Unit, List, ~{
           inds <- match(.x, .y)
           na.omit(.y[c(inds-1, inds, inds+1)])
         }))

#  Unit           List   Adjacent
#1    1        1, 2, 3       1, 2
#2   10             10         10
#3   20     10, 20, 30 10, 20, 30
#4    2           1, 2       1, 2
#5    3     1, 2, 3, 4    2, 3, 4
#6   4A 2A, 3A, 4A, 5A 3A, 4A, 5A
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Unit = c("1", "10", "20", "2", "3", "4A"), 
List = c("1 2 3", "10", "10 20 30", "1 2", "1 2 3 4", "2A 3A 4A 5A")), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   separate_rows(List) %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>%
   slice(match(first(Unit), List) + c(-1, 0, 1)) %>%
   group_by(rn, Unit) %>%
   summarise(Adjacent = str_c(List, collapse=" "), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   select(-rn) %>% 
   right_join(df)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Unit  Adjacent List       
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>      
1 1     1 2      1 2 3      
2 10    10       10         
3 20    10 20 30 10 20 30   
4 2     1 2      1 2        
5 3     2 3 4    1 2 3 4    
6 4A    3A 4A 5A 2A 3A 4A 5A
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Unit = c("1", "10", "20", "2", "3", "4A"), 
List = c("1 2 3", "10", "10 20 30", "1 2", "1 2 3 4", "2A 3A 4A 5A")), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @AnilGoyal ii guess you have a solution in regex right

Comment: Oh yes. Arun I was able to solve it later on. Thanks.